# How can I have a word index for each chapter as well as a word index for the whole book?

Tags: indexing, subdividing

In other words, just the way I get a table of contents at the beginning of each chapter with `titletoc`, I would like to have a word index at the end of each chapter.
(In addition to the index for the whole book at the end of the book.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `latexmk` can't detect that an idx file has been written via the imakeidx package so "makeindex" isn't run. I placed "makeindex" in quotes because what `latexmk` actually runs is determined by a Perl variable, `$makeindex`, and that can be changed in a configuration file. As far as I can tell, if `latexmk` could detect that the idx file was created via the log file one need only set the `$makeindex` variable to run `splitindex` (which splits the index and runs `makeindex` on each split) with the appropriate argument. I'd get in touch with John Collins, the maintainer of `latexmk`, and discuss the what has to be done with him.

PS: the `splitindexmk` engine for TeXShop that I wrote is really a fudge that takes advantage of the fact that `latexmk` does nothing. Basically it first runs `pdflatexmk` (an TeXShop engine using `latexmk`), then `splitindex` and finally a single run of `pdflatex` with appropriate options so that TeXShop can sync properly and also Go

Comment: It is unbelievable that such a desirable feature has never been addressed or implemented. I came expecting for a simple default built in command and was schocked!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a prototype using the `imakeidx` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[noautomatic,splitindex]{imakeidx}

%%% Allocate enough chapter indices
\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<50
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\makeindex[name=\number\count255 chap,title=Word index for Chapter \number\count255]}\x
\repeat
%%% A global index
\makeindex

%%% The user level macros
\newcommand{\gindex}[1]{%
  \index{#1}% global index
  \expandafter\index\expandafter[\thechapter chap]{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\printchapterindex}{%
  \begingroup
  % We want the index as an unnumbered section
  \let\chapter\section
  % Also disable the page break
  \let\cleardoublepage\relax
  % Print the index
  \expandafter\printindex\expandafter[\thechapter chap]%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

First\gindex{first} and abc\gindex{abc}

\printchapterindex

\chapter{Second}

Second\gindex{second} and def\gindex{def}

\printchapterindex

\printindex

\end{document}
```

We can't use the automatic features of `imakeidx` that can work only if the indices are the last thing in the document (or, more precisely, nothing to be indexed follows one of the indices), so the procedure is to call

```
pdflatex filename
splitindex filename
pdflatex filename
```

---

*Image of Chapter 1*

[image]

---

*Image of Chapter 2*

[image]

---

*Image of the global index*

[image]

---

### Appendix: how to add an engine to TeXShop for building this file

1. Navigate in the Finder opening the folder `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` (where `~` stands for your Home.
2. Duplicate the `XeTeX.engine` file.
3. Rename the newly created file to `splitindex.engine`.
4. Right click on this file and choose "Open with TeXShop.app"
5. Change the entire contents of the file with

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   PATH=/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
   bfname=${1%\.*}
   splitindex "$bfname"
   ```
6. Save the file and quit TeXShop

On reopening TeXShop the dropdown menu next to the Typeset button will have an entry called `splitindex`

[image]

When you want to run `splitindex`, just select the item from the dropdown menu and push the Typeset button. This is equivalent to running the command

```
splitindex filename
```

I talked before of. For the next typesetting, choose your default engine from the menu, be it LaTeX or Latexmk.

Comment: Didn't expect such a fast answer so I don't have the time to try right now. I don't understand where the smaller "Chapter" heading comes from but I guess a bit of experimenting will let me find out. In any case, very grateful regards. schremmer

Comment: @user15042 "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2" and "Final index" are just tags preceding the images. I'll make it clearer.

Comment: Got it. Seems just like what I wanted. Will report in a couple of days. Very grateful regards.

Comment: Couldn't resist trying. The pdf doesn't show any index. Looked at imakeidx doc but to no avail. I don't know how to enter the console properly here but some of it is:

Chapter 2.
No file Stack-2chap.ind.
[3] [4]
No file Stack-Stack.ind.

Package imakeidx Warning: Remember to run (pdf)latex again after calling
(imakeidx)                `splitindex' and processing the indices.

I tried to use pdflatexmk (which I always use) but no change.

I am using TeXLive2011 under OSX10.5.8 on a PPC.

Best regards.

Comment: Ooops. I think it has to do with "calling" 
pdflatex filename
splitindex filename
pdflatex filename  which I didn't do because I don't know what it means. Also, Makeindex didn;t accept any entry and rejected 8 entries. Embarrassed regards.

Comment: @schremmer You don't call `makeindex`; it's `splitindex` that takes care of that.

Comment: At egreg: Your code compiled but there was no index in the pdf and while, see above, I got various warnings, I have no idea how to respond to them. So close and yet so far. Embarrassed regards.

Comment: @schremmer My example works on TeX Live 2012. I'll try later on a 2011 version.

Comment: At egreg: I would be much obliged as I am running TeXLive 2011 under 10.5.8 on a Dual 1 GHz PPC G4 so that I am truly stuck.

Comment: @schremmer I tried with TeX Live 2010 and 2011; in both cases I get the expected result.

Comment: At egreg. Thanks for checking. I didn't really think that was it but I really don't know what to do: I call pdflatex via Latexmark and TeXShop but I have no idea how to call splitindex. Sorry for being so obtuse. Regards.

Comment: @schremmer The easiest way is to use the Terminal, or adding an "engine" to TeXShop. Perhaps there's a way to tell `latexmk` to do this, but it surely involves writing a custom dependency file. If you open the Terminal, go to the working directory and launch `splitindex filename`, this should be all that's needed.

Comment: At egreg. Thanks very much. I am terminally afraid of Terminal but now I know what to do: I am going to contact Herbert Schulz from the TeX on Mac OS Mailing List as he is the one who maintains LaTeXMark on TeXShop. I will keep you posted here. Once again, grateful regards.

Comment: At egreg. It's taken me a while to get back because I wanted to make sure that it was working in my set up which involves titledoc for chapter tocs, hyperref and showidx, fixltx2e for indexing math objects, and the particular folder setup I use instead of askinclude. Everything works except that showindex does not show anything in the margins. Could it have to do with the definition of \gindex? In any case, very grateful regards.

Comment: @schremmer Load `showidx` before `imakeidx`; but I'm afraid the version of `imakeidx` coming with TeX Live 2011 is not compatible with `showidx`; full compatibility has been added in the last version.