# Sort custom TOC by name

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, sorting

I have defined a custom TOC with two arguments using `\DeclareNewTOC`:

```
\DeclareNewTOC[
    type=api,
    types=apis,
    float,
    floattype=5,
    name=Api,
    floatpos=ht,
    listname={API-List}
]{loa}
\addtotoclist[api]{api}
```

Currently the entries are listed in the order they appear in the document. Is it possible to order them by name (in my case argument #1)?

It shows up in this form:
[image]

Here is a small compilable document for the image above:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% KOMA Document

\documentclass{scrbook}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Packages

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tabularx, colortbl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Macros

\DeclareNewTOC[
    type=api,
    types=apis,
    float,
    floattype=5,
    name=Api,
    floatpos=ht,
    listname={API-List}
]{loa}
\addtotoclist[api]{api}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\@apifile
\newif\if@apifilewritten
\renewcommand*{\@apifilewrittentrue}{\global\let\if@apifilewritten\iftrue}
\renewcommand*{\@apifilewrittenfalse}{\global\let\if@apifilewritten\iffalse}
\newcommand*{\apioverview}{
    \closeapioverview
    \InputIfFileExists{\jobname-\thechapter.api}{}{
        \typeout{No file `\jobname-\thechapter.api' found.}
    }
}
\newcommand*{\startapioverview}{
    \if@apifilewritten\else
    \if@filesw
    \typeout{Open new api file `\jobname-\thechapter.api'}%
    \@apifilewrittentrue
    \openout\@apifile \jobname-\thechapter.api
    \protected@write\@apifile{}{%
        \string\begin{tabularx}{\string\textwidth}{|X|c|c|}^^J
            \string\hline^^J
            \string\textbf{API}&
            \string\textbf{Method}&
            \string\textbf{Page}\string\\^^J
            \string\hline^^J
            \string\hline
        }%
        \fi
        \fi
    }
    \newcommand*{\closeapioverview}{%
        \if@apifilewritten
        \protected@write\@apifile{}{%
            \string\end{tabularx}%
    }%
    \closeout\@apifile
    \@apifilewrittenfalse
    \fi
}
\newcommand*{\setapientry}[2]{%
    \startapioverview
    \protected@write\@apifile{}{ \detokenize{#1}&\detokenize{#2}&\thepage\string\\^^J \string\hline}%
}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\closeapioverview}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Document Content

\begin{document}    
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Overview}
    \apioverview
    \section{Content}
    \subsection{def}
    \setapientry{def}{SomeMethod}
    \subsection{abc}
    \setapientry{abc}{AnotherMethod}    

    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    \section{Overview 2}
    \apioverview
    \section{Content 2}
    \subsection{jkl}
    \setapientry{jkl}{SomeMethod}
    \subsection{ghi}
    \setapientry{ghi}{AnotherMethod}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: Thx for the hint! I've added an example document.

Comment: TeX etc. is not very well trained about sorting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `makeindex`. Run the file first with `PDFLaTeX`, then run `MakeIndex` and again `PDFLaTeX`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% KOMA Document

\documentclass{scrbook}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Packages
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tabularx, colortbl}

\usepackage{filecontents, makeidx}
\makeindex 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Macros

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
preamble       "\\begin{tabularx}{\\textwidth}{|X|c|c|}\n\\hline\n\\textbf{API}\&\\textbf{Method}\&\\textbf{Page}\\\\\n\\hline\\hline\n"
postamble      "\n\\hline\n\\end{tabularx}\n"
group_skip     "\\hline"
item_0         "\n"
item_1         "\n"
delim_0        "\&"
delim_1        "\&"
delim_t        "\\\\"
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\setapientry}[2]{%
  \index{\detokenize{#1}&\detokenize{#2}}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Document Content

\begin{document}    
    \chapter{Chapter 1}

    \section{Overview}

    %\apioverview
    \printindex

    \section{Content}

    \subsection{def}
    \setapientry{def}{SomeMethod}

    \subsection{abc}
    \setapientry{abc}{AnotherMethod}  

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit 1:** The following makes use of `imakeidx` instead of `makeidx` with a bit of tweaking and hacking and allows for multiple chapters. However it spams the project folder and is a bit slow. You have to run `PDFLaTeX` twice.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% KOMA Document

\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcounter{maxchap}
\setcounter{maxchap}{5}  % Set to the total of chapters in your document

\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<\number\themaxchap
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \expandafter\IfFileExists\expandafter{chap\number\count255.idx}{%
    \immediate\write18{makeindex -s idxstyle.ist chap\number\count255.idx}{}%
  }
\repeat

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Packages
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tabularx, colortbl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}

\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<\number\themaxchap
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
     \noexpand\makeindex[name=chap\number\count255]}\x
\repeat

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Macros

\begin{filecontents}{idxstyle.ist}
preamble       "\\begin{tabularx}{\\textwidth}{|X|c|c|}\n\\hline\n\\textbf{API}\&\\textbf{Method}\&\\textbf{Page}\\\\\n\\hline\\hline\n"
postamble      "\n\\hline\n\\end{tabularx}\n"
group_skip     "\\hline"
item_0         "\n"
item_1         "\n"
delim_0        "\&"
delim_1        "\&"
delim_t        "\\\\"
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\setapientry}[2]{%
  \expandafter\index\expandafter[chap\thechapter]{\detokenize{#1}&\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\apioverview}[1]{%
  \expandafter\InputIfFileExists\expandafter{chap\thechapter.ind}{}{}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Document Content

\begin{document}    
    \chapter{Chapter 1}

    \section{Overview}

    \apioverview

    \section{Content}

    \subsection{def}
    \setapientry{def}{SomeMethod}

    \subsection{abc}
    \setapientry{abc}{AnotherMethod}  


    \chapter{Chapter 2}

    \section{Overview}

    \apioverview

    \section{Content}

    \subsection{jkl}
    \setapientry{jkl}{SomeMethod}

    \newpage

    \subsection{ghi}
    \setapientry{ghi}{AnotherMethod}  

    \subsection{abc}
    \setapientry{abc}{AgainAnotherMethod}   

\end{document}
```

After changes in the document, you should delete all the `chap` files and let the script recreate them.

(I got some inspiration from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94708/47927) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198438/makeindex-and-restricted-write18))

---

**Edit 2:** I merged your approach with mine. It is much quicker than my first try where loads of index files are generated and processed that may be eventually empty. So here is finally a working solution. To be compiled two times with `PDFLaTeX`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% KOMA Document

\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcounter{maxchap}
\setcounter{maxchap}{5}  % Set to the total of chapters in your document

\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<\number\themaxchap
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \expandafter\IfFileExists\expandafter{chap\number\count255.idx}{%
    \immediate\write18{makeindex -s idxstyle.ist chap\number\count255.idx}{}%
  }
\repeat


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Packages

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tabularx, colortbl}

\usepackage{filecontents}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Macros

\begin{filecontents}{idxstyle.ist}
preamble       "\\begin{tabularx}{\\textwidth}{|X|c|c|}\n\\hline\n\\textbf{API}\&\\textbf{Method}\&\\textbf{Page}\\\\\n\\hline\\hline\n"
postamble      "\n\\hline\n\\end{tabularx}\n"
group_skip     "\\hline"
item_0         "\n"
item_1         "\n"
delim_0        "\&"
delim_1        "\&"
delim_t        "\\\\"
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\@apifile
\newif\if@apifilewritten
\renewcommand*{\@apifilewrittentrue}{\global\let\if@apifilewritten\iftrue}
\renewcommand*{\@apifilewrittenfalse}{\global\let\if@apifilewritten\iffalse}
\newcommand*{\apioverview}{
    \closeapioverview
    \InputIfFileExists{chap\thechapter.ind}{}{
        \typeout{No file `chap\thechapter.ind' found.}
    }
}
\newcommand*{\startapioverview}{
    \if@apifilewritten\else
    \if@filesw
    \typeout{Open new idx file `chap\thechapter.idx'}%
    \@apifilewrittentrue
    \openout\@apifile chap\thechapter.idx
    \fi
    \fi
}
\newcommand*{\closeapioverview}{%
    \if@apifilewritten
    \closeout\@apifile
    \@apifilewrittenfalse
    \fi
}
\newcommand*{\setapientry}[2]{%
    \startapioverview
    \protected@write\@apifile{}{ \string\indexentry{\detokenize{#1}&\detokenize{#2}}{\thepage} }%
}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\closeapioverview}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% Document Content

\begin{document}    
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Overview}
    \apioverview
    \section{Content}
    \subsection{def}
    \setapientry{def}{SomeMethod}
    \subsection{abc}
    \setapientry{abc}{AnotherMethod}    

    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    \section{Overview 2}
    \apioverview
    \section{Content 2}
    \subsection{jkl}
    \setapientry{jkl}{SomeMethod}
    \subsection{ghi}
    \setapientry{ghi}{AnotherMethod}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that the index is document wide and not limited to a chapter (as the original code). I've added a second chapter to the example above to show the chapter limitation of the index.

Comment: True, but afaik there are ways to use multiple indices. At least the functionality of `makeindex` allows for sorting

Comment: @abones: The solution is to combine both of our approaches: Use your approach to write custom `idx` files to the working library in a format that can be processed in a second run with `makeindex`. During the processing with `makeindex` the table formatting is made and the sub-tocs are put at the correct places.

Comment: By the way: Vertical lines in tables are considered relatively bad typographical practice. You should have a look at the `booktabs` package when typesetting tables (see eg: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69800/what-are-some-best-practices-for-the-typography-of-tables-and-figures).